# d3.js draw rectangle boxes horizontally in legend

Tags: d3.js, svg

I wanna show legend horizontally on top of the chart, I did something like this:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 30 +
            ")";
    });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 150) + 400;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return 350;
    })
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);
```

My data looks like `Rect1 - North, Rect-2 - North East`, my problem here is just alignment of the legend boxes on top of the scatter plot chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem of drawing a legend horizontally is the text: since `North West` is bigger than `East`, you cannot simply hardcode the values to translate.

In this solution, I'll use `getComputedTextLength` to (as the name implies) get the length of each text and store those values using [D3 locals](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local).

So, when I paint the texts, I store their lengths in the parent `<g>` element:

```
var local = d3.local();

legend.append("text")
  .text(String)
  .attr("y", function() {
    local.set(this.parentNode, this.getComputedTextLength())
    return 20;
  });
```

After that, I use that value both to paint the rectangles...

```
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return local.get(this.parentNode) + 4
  });
```

... and to translate the groups:

```
legend.each(function(d, i) {
  if (i) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + 
        (counter += local.get(this.previousSibling) + 36) + ",0)")
  }
})
```

Here is a demo, using this data:

```
["North", "North East", "North West", "West", "East"];
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["North", "North East", "North West", "West", "East"];
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var local = d3.local();
var legend = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

legend.append("text")
  .text(String)
  .attr("y", function() {
    local.set(this.parentNode, this.getComputedTextLength())
    return 20;
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i)
  })
  .attr("x", function() {
    return local.get(this.parentNode) + 4
  })
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18);

var counter = 0;

legend.each(function(d, i) {
  if (i) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (counter += local.get(this.previousSibling) + 36) + ",0)")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```